# My register tab layout keeps changing design in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I am using Office 365 at work and therefore I have the lastest 2019 update of Access installed and my database is in the latest Access format (should be 2016)
But somehow the design changed in the last few days. (Could be anything, update, setting changed, I don't know).

This is how the design of the tabs looks rn:

[image]

As in the older Versions usual, you have to go to the far right of the tab window to close that tab.

But it should looke somewhat like this:

[image]

It is really annoying to not be able to drag around tabs and close each one individually that way. I dont't know how this option or design is called but I would like to have it back or at least how that is called. When I search on Google, everything that shows up are descriptions about the tab container you can add on a form.

Addition: English is not my native language so I just may be missing the words to find sth on Google for it

Comment: Note that you can use Ctrl+W to close the active tab.

Comment: I know that but my users wont know that sadly. They will be using the same version of Access that I did, Also, not being able to drag around Tabs nags me since I already got used to that

Answer (score 0):

The lower design is from the newest update, meaning that the upper design is from the previous build.

It seems like your two machines are on different *update channels*. So, adjust the machines to be on the same update channel - or live with the differences.

Comment: I am using only 1 Computer. Thats why I got surprised by the "older" Design this morning

Comment: That sounds strange. What is your current build number, please?

Comment: Version 1905 (Build 11629.20246 Click-and-Go) - Monthly Channel. However, is it possible that my IT rolled it back for a reason? That would be strange because I've had the squared tabs for quite a while now and got no notification

Comment: Thanks. Will check at a trusted source ... I see no reason for a roll back but, of course, do check that.

Comment: Okay, I have the square tabs again after starting my pc today. Looked up Build number and it says Version 1905 (Build 11629.20246 Claick-and-Go) Monthly Channel. Strange that the Build number did not change but the layout. I restarted my pc multiple times yesterday so I am completely clueless where this came from